# Eval command works properly, but when it errors it doesn't use `catch {`

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I use eval for some testing outside of the code or console. However, it doesn't tell me if it errored or the result with the error. It just shows the error in the console, without telling me. As a result, whenever the bot doesn't respond to my eval, I have to go all the way to the coding place and restart it to have the bot online again.

I've tried to modify the `catch` script, like removing `(err)` in `catch (err)`.

Here's my code:

```js
const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);

  if (message.content.startsWith(`${p}eval`)) {
    if (message.author.id !== "821682594830614578") {
      message.channel.send(`Eval command can't be used by users, since the command can do anything, even deleting the files of code from a bot.`)
    } else {
      try {
        const evaled = eval(args.join(" "));
        let cleaned = await clean(client, evaled);
        const embedEval = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Eval succeeded')
          .setColor('#00ff8f')
          .addField('Result:', `\`\`\`js\n${cleaned}\n\`\`\``, false)
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter({ text: 'Eval has been succeded.' })
        
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embedEval] });
      } catch {
        message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${cleaned}\n\`\`\``);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does the `eval`ed code do? Does it throw exceptions asynchronously?

Comment: Evaluate (execute) our input. @Bergi

Comment: Why does your `catch` block try to `eval(args.join(" "));` again? That'll just cause the same error again, except this time it won't be caught by anything.

Comment: I removed it. (it still does the same thing though)

Comment: So again, what code did you eval? And what error did it throw that was logged to your console?

Comment: Whenever I do something that errors, it would say something like a ReferenceError or something other than that.

Comment: Hey, when it errors, it **now** says: `ReferenceError: cleaned is not defined`

Comment: Well `cleaned` *is* not defined in ```message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${cleaned}\n\`\`\``);```. You might want to send `err.message` instead

Comment: Alright, that worked. You might want to move that to an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Btw, just to make sure you're clear on why the issue was occurring, `cleaned` is not defined in the `catch` because you defined it only in the `try` block's scope, and also because it is only defined *after* the `eval` is executed. If an error occurs in your eval'd code, the `let cleaned` line is never even reached anyways due to the error. Thus why `err.message` works better.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, some special errors like Invalid Form Body errors to the console, not on err.message